# Creating a new column based on another column in R

Tags: r

I have a data frame that has things like "nasal_coronal" and "coronal" and I want to get rid of "nasal_" and create a new column for things marked with "nasal"

I initially tried to use `grep()` like this:
`data.df$nasal <- grep("^nasal", data$type, value = TRUE)` but R gives me the error that the replacement has less rows than the data set.

Here's code to create a mini dataset.

```
type <- c("nasal_coronal", "nasal_coronal", "coronal")
word <- c("something", "walk", "thing")

data.df <- data.frame(word, type)
```

Comment: You should use the gsub command and not grep.  grep performs a search only.  gsub will perform the search with substitution and return a vector the same length as the original vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to create a column that indicates the 'type' column had `nasal_`, we can use `grep` i.e.

```
data.df$initType <- grepl("nasal_", data.df$type)
```

Then using `sub`, we remove the substring that matches characters until `_` for the 'type' column

```
data.df$type <- sub('.*_', '', data.df$type)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I used `data.df$nasal <- gsub('.*_', '', data.df$type)` but this just makes a column that only says "coronal". I also need to make an additional nasal column that indicates if the type was originally "nasal_coronal". Is this possible?

Comment: @Lisa Updated the post.  I guess you want a logical column to indicate if there was a `nasal_` substring in the type.

Answer (score 1):

Adding/deleting columns in a data frame as follows:

```
 df <- data.frame(1:5, 21:25, 31:35)
 colnames(df) <-c("A","B","C")

 df

 A  B  C
 1 1 21 31
 2 2 22 32
 3 3 23 33
 4 4 24 34
 5 5 25 35

 # delete column "B":
 df$B <-NULL

 df

 df
 A  C
 1 1 31
 2 2 32
 3 3 33
 4 4 34
 5 5 35

 # add new column "extra": 

 df$extra <-rnorm(1:5)

 A  C      extra
 1 1 31  0.6739996
 2 2 32  1.0011144
 3 3 33 -0.1595998
 4 4 34  0.5696583
 5 5 35 -0.4564025
```